# JointJS Paper is not rendered if constructed with "ready" model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events, jointjs

I'm trying to construct a Paper, while I already have a ready model for it.

for example:

```js
var graphModel = new joint.dia.Graph;

/* add cells to graphModel... */

// now construct the Paper to render on screen 
var paper = new joint.dia.Paper({
    el: $('.selector'),
    width: width,
    height: height,
    gridSize: 1,
    model: graphModel
});
```

It looks like the Paper renders upon `add`, `change` events of the it's model, without checking if the model is already populated with cells to render (at initialization phase).

Sometimes the model is coming by a REST response that was already parsed into `graphModel` - so in this case the model is ready (so no need to re-manipulate it) and I just want to render it

Cheers,

Ziv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried calling

```
paper.render();
```

method? This should render the view with the data it already has.

#### Edit

The thing you're looking for is the [`paper#resetCells`](http://www.jointjs.com/api#joint.dia.Graph:resetCells) method. Use it like this (see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dethariel/f5yz202p/2/)):

```
paper.resetCells(graphModel.get("cells"));
```

Comment: yes. it does nothing... `Paper.render` function is not implemented in JointJS

Comment: But it's implemented in `Backbone.View`, which `Paper` "inherits" from

Comment: @ZivLevy updated the answer. Please, let me know if that doesn't work for you

Comment: this is what I've tried to do as a workaround.But unfortunately, if i destroy this view and then re-render it (like when leaving that page and then go back to it), I get this weird error `Error: Invalid value for <g> attribute transform="scale(Infinity,Infinity)"` by `setAttribute` function in `vectorizer`. Even  though nothing has changed in the `model`

Comment: Your last comment has very little to do with the original question. Please, consider opening a new one for that matter.

Comment: you are write and you did solve the original, though I thought there is a more elegant way to do it (or configure it). Thanks!